# Unique ID for each chrome user?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a unique ID for each Chrome User?
So that I on my extension, can save informations on my database, with each user have their own unqiue ID?

Does that exist somehow?

EDIT:
Or can I store informations locally on the users machine? This would make it possible to do the same as I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im sure [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/uEJWWYJ5QXs) answers your question. And for your update, Yes you can use localstorage to store info on the client computer. Hope this helps :)

> Well to track how many installs of your extension, you can add the
>   Google Analytics ID to your extension in your management area for you
>   Chrome Extension Gallery. That will keep track of the installs and
>   updates. Google analytics even has tracking usage, so you can add
>   tracking information based on a specific metric (clicking, logging)
>   etc.
>
> If you meant for each "user" tracking, no, extensions don't identify
>   each individual user, the only thing that is unique is the extension
>   itself with its extension id. You can have other means of identifying
>   a user uniquely through a third party service, such as OAuth, OpenID,
>   or some custom stuff. Then you can associate your authentication to
>   something locally

Answer (score 0):

While identifying a user is not supported without the user actually logging into the app, you could track the install or machine. See this response of mine for details.

[What is the best to identify machine/user in Google Chrome Extention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051224/what-is-the-best-to-identify-machine-user-in-google-chrome-extention/17714453#17714453)